# Moving folder to different folder gives error page not found in xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I had a laravel project in a folder "htdocs/webdev/example", i copied the whole "example" folder to another folder "htdocs/Webeng" now that that example folder is not working, it shows the first view but on form submission it says "page not found" however using artisan serve gives correct output

showForm.blade.php

```
<!-- showForm.blade.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Upload File</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">

                <br><br><br>
                    <!-- store route as action -->
                    <form action="{{route('uploads')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    
                    <!-- value Part -->
                    

                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="thing" id="title">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger" value="Upload" onclick="spinner()">
                    </form>
                    @if (session('message'))
    <h1 id="t">{{ session('message') }}</h1>
@endif
     </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    
    return view('showForm');
})->name("start");


Route::post('/uploads', function (Request $request) {
    
    if($request->file("thing")=="")
    {
        // return back()->withInput();
        return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Insert Data!');
    }
    else
    {
        $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
        $book=DB::table('books')->where('Title',$name)->count();
        if($book>0)
        {
        return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Document already exists!');

        }
        else{

            Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
            $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
            $details=Storage::disk("google")->getMetadata($name);
            $path=$details['path'];
            DB::insert('insert into books (Title, Url, FileId) values (?,?,?)', [$name,$url,$path]);
            return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Successfully uploaded document, you have recieved token!');
        }



    }
})->name("uploads");
```

the request moves to http://localhost/Webeng/example/uploads
which is the correct path, in previous folder it was working but now saying page not found

Edit:
corrected the path mistake still same

Comment: Did you clear the laravel cache?  `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan view:clear`?  Seems like the new path shouldn't have "example" in it which makes me think it's possibly using a cached value somewhere

Comment: No effect, If I copy it to other folders, it works but not in just one folder. Is it because once I cancelled the copying in between? How can I resolve it if that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **showForm.blade.php** you are submitting your form to a route called **upload**.
However, in your routes file you have named the route as **uploads**

Just change `name("uploads")` to `name("upload")` in your routes file and see if it is working

Comment: no it was just a type which posting question